# How to calculate the smallest number in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, arraylist

I have written a program where the user will input 10 numbers and eventually those numbers will be stored in an arraylist.

When the user has finished entering the numbers, I have to find the smallest number in the ArrayList and print it.

My code:

```
package findingsmallestandbiggestnum;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FindingSmallestAndBiggestNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> uInput = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers: ");
            uInput.add(input.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println("You have entered: " + uInput);

        //calculate the smallest integer in the array
        //for (int i = 0; i < uInput.length; i++) {
        //}
    }

}
```

Comment: You already know that you want the smallest number. For a moment, consider yourself the computer - how would *you* go about finding the smallest number, given 10 numbers? Once you have that, the rest just falls into place. :-)

Comment: A side note: package names should be clear and concise.

Comment: How do you find minimal value? What do you do when reading series of unordered numbers when you are interested in minimal/maximal value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Collections.min(uInput);
```

Comment: The OP is probably doing this for homework, so `Collections.min()` probably isn't a viable solution.

Comment: @GriffeyDog, Maybe but OP should tell about this in question

Answer (score 1):

Just run over the list and save the smallest element:

```
int min = uInpunt.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < uInput.size(); i++) {
    int curr = uInput.get(i);
    if (curr < min) {
        min = curr;
    }
}
System.out.println ("The smallest number is: " + min);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the step-by-step version. Also works in situations where there's no numbers.

```
Integer smallest;
for ( Integer num : uInput ) {
  if( smallest == null || num < smallest ) {
    smallest = num;
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd want to initialize `smallest` to `null` though, right? Also, `for` should be lower case.

Comment: I don't think that applies to local variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collections.min](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
int minElement = Collections.min(uInput);
```

Answer (score -2):

A potential work around is to have an index of the smallest one. Off the top of my head untested it would be

```
int smallest = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < uInput.size(); i++) {
    if (uInput.get(i) < smallest) {
        smallest = uInput.get(i);
    }
}
```

This method also works well if you need to find the largest number as you just reverse the logic.

edit: Didn't even realize sorry. Setting the smallest to start as 0 will only work if you are finding the largest number, my mistake. The better solution is to do what mureinik elsewhere in this thread and set

```
int smallest = uInput.get(0);
```